# Posicionar línea con tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo un problema, quiero poner una línea en un sitio en específico, probé hacerlo mediante place pero me dio error. Editando los números que vienen en los paréntesis para crear la línea simplemente sirven para moverla en diagonal o hacerla mas larga.

El código:

```
from tkinter import *
canvas = Canvas(width=400, height=300, bg='white')
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
canvas.create_line(10, 10, 80, 80).place(x=200, y=50)
canvas.create_line(10, 80, 80, 10).place(x=300, y=70)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Tu código tiene muchos errores, yo creo que hay que repasar la documentación y varios conceptos. Utilizas variables que no has definido en ningún lugar, utilizas métodos que no existen (`create_line` no tiene el método `place`), el orden de las líneas es incorrecto y no defines `Tk()`

Ejemplo completo:

```
from tkinter import *

# Definimos Tk para inicializar el intérprete y crear la ventana principal
main = Tk()

# Creamos el canvas, nota, el primer argumento es la ventana principal creada en la línea anterior
canvas = Canvas(main, bg="blue", height=250, width=400)

# Los puntos siempre son x1, y1, x2, y2, ... , xn, yn
# Esto crea una línea diagonal
canvas.create_line(150, 30, 240, 210)

# Esto crea una línea vertical y segmentada
canvas.create_line(300, 35, 300, 200, dash = (5, 2))

# Esto crea un triángulo
canvas.create_line(55, 85, 155, 85, 105, 180, 55, 85)

# "Empaquetamos" el canvas
canvas.pack()

# Ejecutamos el ciclo de la ventana principal
main.mainloop()
```

Lectura recomendada: [Documentación de tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html)

**Nota adicional:** Es recomendable no importar todos los elementos de un módulo/librería utilizando el asterisco `*`, ya que podría ser que dos librerías tuvieran funciones, clases u otros objetos con el mismo nombre, por lo general se importan los paquetes con un alias, por ejemplo las primeras 3 líneas del código anterior quedarían así:

```
import tkinter as tk

# Definimos Tk para inicializar el intérprete y crear la ventana principal
main = tk.Tk()

# Creamos el canvas, nota, el primer argumento es la ventana principal creada en la línea anterior
canvas = tk.Canvas(main, bg="blue", height=250, width=400)
```

Comment: No es necesario el Buen Dia, la respuesta va dirigida a toda la comunidad. La zona horaria no es la misma y cuando alguien la lea no necesariamente lo hará en horas del día. Evita los saludos personalizados, no aportan realmente nada a la respuesta. No lo tomes a mal, pero es realmente *ruido*.

Comment: Por eso no es "Buenos días", "Buenas tardes" o "Buenas noches", buen día aplica para cualquier hora y es por cortesía.

Comment: Artículo relacionado: [Saludar o no saludar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4282/saludar-o-no-saludar). Seguir las normas y reglas del sitio es parte de lo que se espera de los participantes de la comunidad. Saludos

Comment: Ya veo, gracias por la información, voy a considerarlo pero una interacción humana donde no se inicia con un saludo se me hace bastante extraña. Saludos!

Comment: @MauricioContreras lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5394/158880. Los saludos son ruido, pero vale más ser amable que quitar todo ruido de la respuesta.

Comment: @DanteS. La amabilidad no hace la pregunta o respuesta mejor o peor. La amabilidad se sobre entiende cuando respondes una pregunta. Un saludo no agrega o aporta nada a una respuesta que intenta ser técnica. No he encontrado ningún manual oficial de ningún lenguaje de programación, librería, framework, etc. que comience con un saludo. ¿Será que quienes lo escribieron son descorteses o poco amables?

Comment: @MauricioContreras nunca dije que una respuesta sea mejor por tener un saludo ni que alguien sea descortes por no poner un saludo (mis respuestas no comienzan por saludos). De acuerdo contigo que no aporta nada. Pero, está bueno que colocar saludos en una publicación esté en manos del autor, y no que otro venga a decir "es ruido, no lo pongas". Es verdad que es ruido, pero también es un gesto amable. Te recomiendo leer la respuesta y comentarme tu opinión allí la proxima.

Comment: Creo que los comentarios nos llevaron a otro tema que no pertenece a la pregunta y esto sí sería ruido, recomiendo borrar los comentarios de aquí y tal vez discutirlo en el chat o en Meta. Gracias a ambos por la información, en lo personal creo que un saludo corto no afecta a la respuesta.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, cuando Mauricio me de el ok, lo borro.